# Aligning items on the same row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chartkick

I am using a rails gem called chartkick.

I can't line up two charts on one row in a view. They always line up on top of each other like separate divs would. I tried sticking these into a table or span without any luck. Any idea how to go around this?

```
    <span>
    <%= line_chart Client.sum(:bill_charge) %>
    </span>
    <span>
    <%= bar_chart Client.sum(:bill_charge) %>
    </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would look into the css.

It's the element you should work on to fix your issue.

Look at how your charts are created, what are the rules on their containers and act regarding this, perhaps by wrapping the charts with a custom class using inline block and a defined width ?

Comment: Yeah I've tried all kinds of floating and inline tags. Problem is the controls are getting overwritten in the gem itself. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: @HoosierCoder what do you mean by overwritten ? The parents are being modified with inline cuss or something like that ? If you use bootstrap or some kind of css framework with a grid, could you try to encompass your charts with a row and two elements of the same size with a chart in each ?